# Button does not animate when pressed iOS

Tags: ios

I've programatically added buttons in xcode, but when I run this through the simulator, it doesn't animate, i.e. it doesn't flash like it usually does?

This is how I've added a button:

```
closeButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(505, 5, 20, 20);
[closeButton setImage:imgBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[closeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:closeButton];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
closeButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(505, 5, 20, 20);
[closeButton setImage:imgBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[closeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:closeButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to see touch event

```
closeButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Or you have to use button type `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` to see the button pressed effect.